I comply with backoff orders, but still get "Violation of backoff parameter"
I sometimes get throttle violation errors from the API
 {'error_id': 502, 'error_message': 'Violation of backoff parameter', 'error_name': 'throttle_violation'}

despite complying with back off orders received from the API. I double- and triple-checked my logs and verified that the required time passed between the moments I receive the backoff parameter (always 10 seconds in my case) and send the next request. I also have set up a 25 requests per second limit for when requests go smoothly.
This used to happen more often in the past, but things were better since I started to add 0.5 seconds just in case the time get rounded to integer seconds. This 0.5s margin seemed to help, but now I see such "violations" again. I want to be with API on friendly terms and be always respectful of her boundaries.
Is there anything I am doing wrong? What could be the source of the problem? What can I do to avoid it? What are my options if I cannot avoid it?

I have checked potential suspects, as suggested in related posts:

rate limit is below 30 requests per second, besides, I inspected my logs to confirm request timing
no other processes that might make API requests from the same IP [comment]
all requests are made sequentially, no requests fly in parallel [comment]


25 requests per second is way too high. You say that no requests fly in parallel. In order for you to have 25 requests per second, the requests would each need to take < 40 milliseconds. That just doesn't happen, unless you're just getting errors. Hmm... I guess maybe, if the requests are nearly trivial. In normal operation with a semi-normal mix of requests, if you only have one request in flight at a time, and aren't getting errors, then you won't come close to 25 requests/second.

Briefly looking at a couple of requests a userscript I use/work on, FIRE, made, a request to the /posts/{ids} endpoint, asking for a single post, took 490 ms, while an immediately subsequent request to the /questions/{id}/flag/options endpoint for the same question took 116 ms. So, it's highly unlikely that you're approaching 25 requests/s, if you only have one request in flight at a time. I should note that you can have multiple requests in flight at the same time. I have a userscript that does that up to configurable amount. I've actively used between 5 and 10 requests in flight.

@Makyen "25 requests per second is way too high. ... the requests would each need to take < 40 milliseconds." - Actually, I don't know if I ever reached this rate, it is just a constraint set in code. "asking for a single post, took 490 ms, while [a related request] took 116 ms" - I have request series with /users/{ids}/reputation-history?page=1, page=2 and so on. I haven't timed them, but they seem fast. Possibly some smart preemptive caching takes on the SE API side.

Regarding 25 requests per second, I think it is realistic when paging is involved. Here is a sample of my request series (#pages/#seconds, rounded without distorting the meaning): 200/10, 300/20, 230/15, 160/9.5, 320/19, 260/16.2, 143/7.5, 500/32.7. So within the range 15-20 r/s, and I have some Python overhead like collecting response.json() and logging.

The short answer is: you're going to get those errors, regardless of what you do, potentially even making a single request. Your code just needs to deal with having received the error and recover operation.
Without your code, there's no way for us to say if you're doing something wrong, but that you are getting Violation of backoff parameter errors doesn't, necessarily, mean that you are actually violating a backoff that SE's API has sent to you.
That error can be sent by the SE API without you having to actually violate a backoff or without the SE API giving you any prior indication that it wants you to make fewer requests. That you get that error, or the other ways SE throttles consumers of the SE API, will depend on the loading that you are putting on the SE API and the overall load that the SE API is experiencing from everybody's requests.
Basically, if you get any of the errors that indicate throttling, then you need to wait some amount of time. If you weren't provided by the SE API an amount of time, then you'll need to pick a time to wait. After that time expires, try a single request. If you don't get an error, then you can, generally, go back to normal operation.

Yup, this is exactly what I independently discovered in my own development of a bot that uses the SE API. It was very frustrating to be told, effectively, that you were doing it wrong (violating the backoff parameter), even though you were, by all available evidence, following all of the documented rules. I could not find this documented anywhere. I ended up doing the exact same thing, waiting some arbitrary, predefined length of time (20 seconds in my case), then trying again. The API request virtually always works the next time.

It's also worth noting that there was a feature request years ago to fix this by returning a suggested backoff value in the event of such errors so that you aren't just guessing at what an appropriate time would be (and thus risking another backoff error by guessing a time that is not long enough). Unfortunately, 9 years later, this basic feature is still not implemented.

I found that adding two seconds to the backoff was enough for the majority of my use

Is it something you discovered on your own or you inferred from the Throttles page? I don't see this case (receiving a "Violation of ..." because of overall load) explained on this page.
